# How can I improve image display quality?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

[Original image](https://img4.manga-chan.me/manga/-9new/t/1568958338_the-gamer-tom-4-glava-290/001.png)

[Screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/tjXNCccafGtoHcuU7)

When I try to load an image in my application, it feels like it is somehow not stretching properly.
I tried all the options for the "fit" parameter
And nothing happened

It's my code

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    width: width,
    child: Image.network(
      'https://img4.manga-chan.me/manga/-9new/t/1568958338_the-gamer-tom-4-glava-290/001.png',
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
)
```

What should I do to make the image of original quality?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did it and it helped me

Wrapped scroll in container

```dart
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Container(
  width: width,
  height: height,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Image.network(
      'https://img4.manga-chan.me/manga/-9new/t/1571807955_the-gamer-tom-4-glava-296/002.png',
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: @JoãoSoares I put the scroll in the container and assigned it a fixed screen width and height. After that, the image inside the scroll began to stretch correctly.

Comment: Ah. So it wasn't actually a problem of image quality, it was how you had defined the sizing. Your question and answer are a bit misleading.